# CQWP make path relative for Image

Tags: content-query-web-part

Hi I've added a CQWP and edited the item.xslt to provide a new Item Style. In the webpart properties (Fields to display) I've added columns for Image, Title and Description.

The CQWP is expecting a path like /sites/siteA/doclib/image1.jpg for Image field.

However I dont want to provide the full path in the column (text)  but only the library and filename (/doclib/image1.jpg)

This is because I want to create a site template and having a absolute path wont work. I've tried making the list column equal ../doclib/image1.jpg but that doesnt work.

Can the webpart be edited to provide the first part of the path dynamically like /sites/currentsite and append the incoming remainder of /doclib/image1.jpg?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In item.xslt, first define parameter `<xsl:param name="HttpVDir"/>` then before relative URL of your image, use the value `<xsl:value-of select="$HttpVDir" />` to get the URL of the current website that contains the list.

[XSLT Global Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806158(v=office.14).aspx)